# How does JQuery empty() method work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I know that the empty method removes all children in the DOM element.

In this example however, why does removing the empty method result in duplicate entries:

[image]

and putting it in results in a normal page:

[image]

```
var renderNotesList = function() 
{
    var dummyNotesCount = 10, note, i;

    var view = $(notesListSelector);
    view.empty();

    var ul = $("<ul id =\"notes-list\" data-role=\"listview\"></ul>").appendTo(view);

    for (i=0; i<dummyNotesCount; i++) 
    {
        $("<li>"+ "<a href=\"index.html#note-editor-page?noteId=" + i + "\">" + "<div>Note title " + i + "</div>" + "<div class=\"list-item-narrative\">Note Narrative " + i + "</div>" + "</a>" + "</li>").appendTo(ul);
    }
    ul.listview();
};
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: What browser/device makes problem ? Have you google about that browser/device and `empty()` ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why `empty()` doesn't work but I found this

> ... so until this is sorted everyone should just use:
>   **el.children().remove();** instead of **el.empty();**

( [jQuery.empty() does not destroy UI widgets, whereas jQuery.remove() does (using UI 1.8.4)](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-empty-does-not-destroy-ui-widgets-whereas-jquery-remove-does-using-ui-1-8-4) )

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how your JavaScript is being used in your page, I suspect that you must be calling the `renderNotesList()` function twice and thus generating to unordered lists.

When you use the `.empty()` method, you are removing the first `ul` list, so you only see one instance.  Without the call to `.empty()`, you retain both.

However, I can't say where or how this is happening in you web page without seeing more, but at least you now have some idea of what to look for.

**Demo Fiddle**

I built a demo using your JavaScript, but I was sort of guessing as to how you are using it.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/UVymE/

**Footnote**

It occurred to me that the function `ul.listview()` may actually be appending a second copy of the `ul` to the DOM.  You need to check the code or post it for further review.